# Why are non-positive strides disallowed in the blas gemm family of functions?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, blas, stride

[The netlib documentation of sgemm](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/dc9/group__single__blas__level3_gafe51bacb54592ff5de056acabd83c260.html#gafe51bacb54592ff5de056acabd83c260) states that the array strides `LDA` and `LDB` must be `>= 1`, and large enough so that columns don't overlap. Indeed, the implementation in Apple's Accelerate/veclib framework checks these conditions and exists if they are violated.

I really don't understand why this limitation exists. Can't BLAS simply believe me that I really want a stride of zero, or a negative stride? As far as I understand, Fortran integers are signed by default, so parameter types don't seem to be the reaons (disclaimer: I don't know Fortan very well).

Indeed, there exist very reasonable use cases of non-positive array strides:

- zero stride: in a multi-dimensional array class, a stride of zero enables numpy-style broadcasting.
- negative stride: negating a stride allows to view an array in reverse order along any axis without copying. This can be useful e.g. when flipping convolution kernels, [and convolutions can be implemented efficiently using gemm](https://petewarden.com/2015/04/20/why-gemm-is-at-the-heart-of-deep-learning/). Alternatively, the vertical axis of an image can be flipped, which is handy since there exist different conventions: axis pointing upwards in postscript/pdf, and downwards in the png format (and many others).

I am interested in two aspects:

1. I'd like to understand why the restriction exists. Is it really just because the designers of BLAS did not think about such use cases? Am I the victim of someone trying to catch a bug that's indeed a feature? Or does the restriction result in better performance? I have a hard time imagining the latter.
2. Is there a way to work around the restriction without sacrificing (too much) performance? For now I need something that works on a Mac in C++, but long term it should still be based on BLAS, so it works across platforms.

Comment: Your second question sounds awfully like an off-site resource recommendation, which is strictly off topic

Comment: @Puppy: I see your point, but I don't agree. I did not intend to ask something along the lines of "what's your favorite BLAS alternative?", but rather "is there any alternative available for this specific case?" - I have a real problem to solve.

Comment: Did you try using negative numbers? Does it work (e.g. in non-debug mode)? Does the library check? If not then it could be possible still. . Just guessing here, maybe the constrain is to maintain performance, do memory caches work in reverse order? I agree it is an arbitrary restriction, the case of `LDA = 0` may be justified by the `aliasing` (two restricted pointers pointing to the same memory), but the `LDA < 0` case seems arbitrary.

Comment: @alfC: I agree with your comment. Of course I tried it out. The function quits with an error, indicating an invalid parameter value.

Comment: @tglas i don't know how, but there must be a way to suppress parameter checking from the library and that will allow you to use negative strides. I am very curious of what you find.

Comment: @tglas, I found this, http://www.netlib.org/lapack/faq.html#_problems_running_the_blas_test_suite_with_an_optimized_blas_library . I am not sure if it helps. It seems to be possible to compile  BLAS without input checks. I think it has to work ©. Let us know.

Comment: @alfC, ideally, on my Mac I'd like to stick to the pre-compiled and well-optimized accelerate framework. But anyway, thanks for the hint, I'll check it out!

Comment: I have two new theories: 1) the C (Fortran?) abstract machine only guarantees the address just after the last allocated element is valid. This creates an assymmetry when iterating forward or backwards (with pointers). This is the same reason that in C++ `std::reverse_iterator` exists and has a peculiar implementation. OR 2) reversing indices  is not trivial when 2D subblocks need to be defined (which is what ultimately makes BLAS efficient, not all BLAS algorithms are implemented as simple loops the code can be really complicated) that can to too many cases to code, specially in two dimensions

Answer (score 1):

I recently found myself effectively doing this:

```
double s[4] = {10., 2., 3.1, 4.1};
dscal_(4, 3., s, -1);
assert( s[1] == 2.*3. );
```

`dscal_` is the simplest BLAS function, multiplying an array by a scalar, its signature is:

```
void sscal(int, double, double*, int); // doesn't seem to return anything useful
```

In my particular distribution of BLAS (shipped with Fedora 28) this gave a silent error, as the function doesn't seem to do anything.
Moreover, `dscal_` doesn't even seem to return an error code, so there is no way I can catch this error without a wrapping function (my arrays have runtime positive or negative strides but I cannot control the value in all cases).

All these cases failed:

```
double s[4] = {10., 2., 3.1, 4.1};
dscal_(4, 3., s, -1); // negative incx does nothing
dscal_(4, 3., &s[4], -1); // negative incx does nothing
dscal_(-4, 3., &s[4], 1); // negative n does nothing
dscal_(-4, 3., &s[4], -1); // negative n or incx does nothing
assert( s[1] == 2. );
```

This tells me that, although probably not documented anywhere the stride (`incx`) has to be positive, (and also the size).
Fortunately, for many BLAS function the call can be converted into positive strides.
I needed a wrapper function to debug this any way, so wrote the folloing wrapper function:

```
void signed_dscal(int n, double alpha, double* x, int incx){
    int prod = incx*n;
    if(prod > 0) dscal(abs(n), alpha, x, abs(incx));
    else         dscal(abs(n), alpha, x + prod, abs(incx));
}
```

In this way, I can call `signed_dscal` with positive or negative strides and sizes.

```
int main(){
{
    double d[4] = {10., 2., 3.1, 4.1};
    signed_dscal(4, 3., d, 1);
    assert( d[1] == 6. );
}
{
    double d[4] = {10., 2., 3.1, 4.1};
    signed_dscal(4, 3., &d[4], -1);
    assert( d[1] == 6. );
}
{
    double d[4] = {10., 2., 3.1, 4.1};
    signed_dscal(-4, 3., &d[4], 1);
    assert( d[1] == 6. );
}
{
    double d[4] = {10., 2., 3.1, 4.1};
    signed_dscal(-4, 3., d, -1);
    assert( d[1] == 6. );
}    
    return 0;
}
```

(Note that `incx=0` still is a case impossible to amend.)

I still don't understand what is the logic behind this. Perhaps some implementation of BLAS will let you do this by default and others will try to protect against infinite loops which as a side effect will assume positive stride values.

---

Intel BLAS seems to imply that it supports negative strides because it mentions `abs(incx)`, at least for AXPY: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/blas-routines/blas-level-1-routines-and-functions/cblas-axpy.html

I didn't try and remains to be seen if it applies to other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the case of zero strides:
I am using a C++ multidimensional array library (disclaimer: my own) that supports broadcasting and BLAS interfaces.
I can try many cases quickly to see what BLAS versions support zero strides.

Here is the example of `axpy`; in Linux at least, all the versions of BLAS I have available support zero strides (broadcasted arrays).

```cpp
#include<multi/array.hpp>  // from https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi
#include<multi/adaptors/blas.hpp>

namespace multi = boost::multi;

int main() {
    multi::array<double, 1> y = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

    // regular arrays, stride != 0
    multi::array<double, 1> const x = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

    multi::blas::axpy(1.0, x.begin(), y);

    assert(y[0] == 2.0);
    assert(y[1] == 3.0);
    assert(y[2] == 4.0);

    // broadcasted array of 0D into 1D, stride == 0
    multi::array<double, 0> const x0(1.0);

    // x0.broadcasted() is {..., 1.0, 1.0, ...}

    multi::blas::axpy(1.0, x0.broadcasted().begin(), y);

    assert(y[0] == 3.0);
    assert(y[1] == 4.0);
    assert(y[2] == 5.0);
}
```

The program compiles and runs correctly with BLAS (netlib), openBLAS, MKL, NVHPC (PGI), ATLAS and BLIS.
(Unfortunately, I don't have a Mac device to Apple libs.)

The good news is that none of these libraries check for zero strides and give the correct answer, at least for `axpy`.

```bash
c++ axpy.cpp -Iinclude/ `pkg-config --libs blas` && ./a.out
c++ axpy.cpp -Iinclude/ `pkg-config --libs openblas` && ./a.out
c++ axpy.cpp -Iinclude/ `pkg-config --libs mkl-static-ilp64-seq` && ./a.out
c++ axpy.cpp -Iinclude/ /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/23.9/compilers/lib/libblas.so && ./a.out
c++ axpy.cpp -Iinclude/ `pkg-config --libs blas-atlas` && ./a.out
c++ axpy.cpp -Iinclude/ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blis64-openmp/libblas64.so && ./a.out
```